# Me ayudan a corregir mi codigo

Tags: python-3.x

```
def calcular(h,n,i):
    r=i/(100*12)

    m=((h*r)/(1-(1+r)**(-12*n)))
    return(m)

print ("\n""$""Cuota mensual")      
print(calcular(150000,15,4.75,))

a=calcular(150000,15,4.75)
def pago(m,n):

    n=(n*12)

    total=(m*n)

    return(total)

print ("\n""$""Intereses totales")      
print(pago(1166.75,15))

b=pago(1166.75,15)

def interes(total,h):
    v=(total-h)

    return(v)
print ("\n""$""Intereses pagados")  
print(interes(210015,150000))

c=interes(210015,150000)
def capital_inicial(v,h):
    porcentaje=((v*100)/(h))
    return(porcentaje)
print ("\n""%""Porcentaje total de intereses pagados")
print(capital_inicial(60015,150000))
```

en el print(pago(1166.75,15)) , como hago que se guarde el valor 1166.75, del primer procedimiento , y no tenga que especificarlos como lo hice aqui.

Gracias

Comment: Hola Oscar, en vez de llamar a las funciones dentro del `print`, realiza las llamadas fuera, asigna el retorno a una variable y usa la variable para el `print` y como argumento para las otras funciones. Es decir, como haces con las variables a, b y c, que por cierto no usas. Por ejemplo, `cuota_mensual = calcular(150000, 15, 4.75)`; `print(cuota_mensual)`; `pago(cuota_mensual, 15)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma de hacerlo es asignando el resultado de cada uno de tus cálculos a una variable y utilizándola como parámetro para los siguientes cálculos.

En concreto, tu código quedaría así:

```
def calcular(h,n,i):
    r=i/(100*12)

    m=((h*r)/(1-(1+r)**(-12*n)))
    return(m)

print ("\n""$""Cuota mensual")    
a=calcular(150000,15,4.75)

print(a)

def pago(m,n):

    n=(n*12)

    total=(m*n)

    return(total)

print ("\n""$""Intereses totales") 
b=pago(a,15)
print(b)


def interes(total,h):
    v=(total-h)

    return(v)
print ("\n""$""Intereses pagados") 
c=interes(b,150000)

print(c)

def capital_inicial(v,h):
    porcentaje=((v*100)/(h))
    return(porcentaje)
print ("\n""%""Porcentaje total de intereses pagados")
print(capital_inicial(c,150000))
```

Espero que te haya resultado de ayuda

Comment: Gracias bro :D!